# Url for custom method in django apiview

Tags: django, url, routes

I am new in Django and I am bit confused in Django `apiview` for custom method.
In ApiView, How can I create a custom method and How to call from axios.

For example

Here is my View

```
class TimeSheetAPIView(APIView):    

    @action(methods=['get'], detail=False)    
    def getbytsdate(self, request):
        return Response({"timesheet":"hello from getbydate"})

    def get(self,request,pk=None):
        if pk:
            timesheet=get_object_or_404(TimeSheet.objects.all(),pk=pk)
            serializer = TimeSheetSerializer(timesheet)
            return Response({serializer.data})
        timesheet=TimeSheet.objects.all()
        serializer = TimeSheetSerializer(timesheet,many=True)
        return Response({"timesheet":serializer.data})
```

Here is my URL=>

```
    url(r'^timesheets_ts/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', TimeSheetAPIView.as_view()),
    url(r'^timesheets_ts/', TimeSheetAPIView.as_view()),
```

Normally my url would be like=>

```
api/timesheet_ts/
```

this one will get all of my records.

So my question is how can I setup URL for `getbytsdate` or `getbyname` or other some kind of custom get method? and how can I call?

I tried like this way=>

```
url(r'^timesheets_ts/getbytsdate/(?P<tsdate>[-\w]+)/$', TimeSheetAPIView.as_view()),
```

and I called like that

```
api/timesheets_ts/getbytsdate/?tsdate='test'
```

Its not work.

So please can u explain for the custom method in `apiview` and url setting?

Answer (score 5):

In addition to your implementation, you just need to show your custom get request to your `urls.py`. Edit your `urls.py` as follows:

```py
# urls.py

timesheet_getbytsdate_detail = TimeSheetAPIView.as_view({'get': 'getbytsdate'})
timesheet_detail = TimeSheetAPIView.as_view({'get': 'retrieve'})

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^timesheets_ts/getbytsdate/(?P<tsdate>[-\w]+)/$', getbytsdate_detail),
    url(r'^timesheets_ts/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/', timesheet_detail),
]
```

**EDIT**: You need to use the combination `viewsets.GenericViewSet` and `mixins.RetrieveModelMixin` instead of `APIVew`to get use of that:

```py
class TimeSheetAPIView(viewsets.GenericViewSet, mixins.RetrieveModelMixin):    

    @action(methods=['get'], detail=False)    
    def getbytsdate(self, request):
        return Response({"timesheet":"hello from getbydate"})

    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        timesheet=self.get_object()
        serializer = TimeSheetSerializer(timesheet)
        return Response({serializer.data})
        timesheet=TimeSheet.objects.all()
        serializer = TimeSheetSerializer(timesheet,many=True)
        return Response({"timesheet":serializer.data})
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried as u said, but its say invalid syntax near 'get':'getbytsdate'

Comment: stil show the error => as_view() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: I think your error is because of your other view. I've just put the whole ```urls.py``` for your.

Comment: Can u give me documentation link for this 'get'? I still get the error and don't know why.

Comment: Ok I understand the error you get. Just modify your ```getbytsdate``` declaration in your views.py from ```def getbytsdate(self, request):``` to ```def getbytsdate(self, request, tsdate=None):```. As you are providing a query parameter in your ```urls.py``` you need to catch it from your function declaration.

Comment: Finally I know, this as_view({'get':'........'}) is used in ViewSet, Not APIView. My view is APIView that's why I can't do as u said.

Comment: You are right, I have included an edit in my answer.